# HighCharts multiple data points per category

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want the multiple data points to be plotted on category. In the below example case , for "Jan" month I would like to plot multiple data points instead of one. Something like [20,28] in the same vertical line. Please see the series that I've for Tokyo and Jan month. I would like to pass an array of data points instead of single. (Example [20,28] instead of 28)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [[20,28], 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below approach to plot data point to same vertical.

```js
$(function () {
     $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'scatter'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            title: {
                text: 'Months'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                enableMouseTracking: false
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [[0, 20], [0, 28], [1, 6.9], [2, 9.5],[3, 14.5],[4, 18.4], [5, 21.5], [6, 25.2], [7, 26.5], [8, 23.3], [9, 18.3], [10, 13.9], [11, 9.6]]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Any way to do that with a different color for the second data points?  Then multiple colors for that category (e.g., top half orange, bottom half blue) in the legend color dot?  The idea would be the second data points have different metadata, - like street location, but still Tokyo - listed in the tooltip